# How to fix maximum add related product magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am getting error add more related products . The number of products I want to add to the related product is 100 . But I get this error, is there any way to solve this problem. Thanks.
https://prnt.sc/_DDCqiagUazd

https://prnt.sc/fsXS43FrK_xR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like your **max_input_vars** is reached maximum input variable.

Please Increase max_input_vars to 10000 and try to assign products

---

**.htaccess**

You can set it through .htaccess  file php_value max_input_vars 10000

OR

---

**php.ini**

max_input_vars = 10000

Comment: Thank you problem solved.

Comment: great !! have a nice day